# react children component rendered twice?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've a simple child component that have string props, and why is it rendered twice at first laod?

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <MyChild a={1} b={2} />
    </div>
  );
}

const MyChild = ({ a, b }) => {
  console.log("hi"); //called twice?
  return <h1>hi</h1>;
};
```

demo https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-lamport-pesw42?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Due to StrictMode, check the docs

Comment: so in reality it's just render once?

Comment: I guess "in reality" you mean in production, yes in production it renders once and in development it renders twice. BTW if you so concern regarding renders, you really should research about "premature optimization"

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-curran-rbyyhn?file=/src/index.js

Remove StrictMode in index.js.

It makes react render twice